# Avoiding using ee.Algorithm.If for null ee.image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to exclude the high values in an ee.Image in Google Earth Engine (GEE).

Before making reduceRegion to estimate the 90% percentiles, I used `updateMask(image.gt(0))` to exclude the invalid values, since zeros in the image affected the calculations of percentiles.

```
image_maksed = image.updateMask(image.gt(0))
```

Then, I used the masked image to obtain the 90% percentiles:

```
q90 = ee.Number(image_maksed.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.percentile([90]), \
geometry=aoi, scale=30, bestEffort=True).get('fai'))
```

Ideally, I can use `updateMask(image.gt(q90))` to exclude the high values directly. However, `image_maksed` might be null after masking, because `ee.Image` does not recieve the input of `null`.

Thus, I have to utilize `ee.Algorithms.If` to avoid the error:

```
 mask = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(q90, image_maksed .lte(q90), image.gt(0)))
 image_result = image_masked.updateMask(mask)
```

However, **ee.Algorithms.If is not a good choice, which significantly reduced the performance in a large imagecollection and is time-consuming.**

I would like to improve the codes, e.g., whether reduceRegions might return null as a value (0), so `ee.Image(null)` would work. I actually thought about using `ee.Filters`, but it is not easy to justify whether the image is null before `updateMask`.

Could someone has some suggestions without `ee.Algorithms.If`?